# Recommend Automated test tools for cross platform including IE and .NET software

Tags: automated-testing, selenium, robotframework

I'm working in an QA team.

We do the automated work from the scratch. So many testing methods may be anti-pattern or disobey some discipline.

We pay lots of effort on test web pages on our products.

Our test cases are based on `Robot framework` and use the selenium library for testing web pages.

I found my members write those code by looking up  the html source code to find the `id` or `name` of the `DOM element`. (Because some of element in DOM without ID.)

Even worse, the same function buttons' `DOM id` are differs from many product.

So I just think the way we build the automated testing code is too slow.

I thought if there is an tool that can record our all actions'  on web pages and turn it into Robot framework script  or other testing framework scripts is more effective ?

If there any good tool for the purpose ?

Second.

We test the `.NET` software by auto-it.
Is there any GUI Software testing tool can cross platforms even on `Android` or `iOS` ?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Many people's first encounter with automation is to start with a record and playback tool.  You quickly learn the limitations of that method because the code it produces is crude and not very maintainable.

I do know some people who continue to use a recorder only for the purpose of getting the ID's or other unique identifiers, however there is still a manual process to take the ID's from the generated code and insert it into your own code.

In my experience, every browser now has very good built in developer tools that make inspecting an element and finding a unique identifier pretty simple.  I would suggest staying away from recorders as it would likely complicate your process instead of simplify it.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at TestCafe from DevExpress. It provides cross-platform testing in multiple browsers simultaneously.

Disclaimer: I work on the TestCafe team. I'd love to help you learn more about it and to hear any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

if you are UI does not change that frequently, it is worth while to investigate on the usage of Sikuli

Comment: Could you give some more information about why Sikuli would be helpful for this person?

Comment: Well, he asks about a tool that can record actions on web pages and about any GUI Software testing tool can cross platforms even on Android or iOS. It seems to fit Sikuli functionality..

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest two options for you:

1. If your app is more like a UI testing, please try using Sikuli. It does not matter which language you have used, if it is on screen, Sikuli can test it.
2. If you want more involved testing, including UI & functional, try Ranorex.

Sikuli is free open source:
[Sikuli Project](http://www.sikuli.org/).

Ranorex is paid but gives you a trial, plus they are very helpful in your PoC & afterP: [Ranorex Studio: Functional UI Test Automation](http://www.ranorex.com/).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is any ready-made tool for this purpose.

But for record and play, the most stable tool is Hp QTP. Once the script is recorded then you can run the scripts on any browser you want (provided you have installed the required QTP browser patch).

Its very simple, if you are interested then you can Google and easily find more details on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you need automated testing only under Windows OS, then try Telerik testing-framework - it is exactly for .NET software, and has a lot of useful stuff.

Answer (score -2):

In my experience, I think you can use MTAS: msys-tech.com; I am working for the company for a while. The tool should be able to help in various functional testing requirements.